# Install Cherrypy for Python3.3

Tags: installation

Please assist me to install Cherrypy3.2 to work/run on Python3.3. I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and have Python3.3 installed already. I had downloaded Cherrypy3.2.2 and had tried to install it without any error messages noticed BUT when I try to import cherrypy I get an error message.

here's what I get.

```
aspire@aspire:~$ python3.3 -c "import cherrypy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py3.3.egg/cherrypy/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from cherrypy import process
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py3.3.egg/cherrypy/process/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cherrypy.process import plugins, servers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py3.3.egg/cherrypy/process/plugins.py", line 424, in <module>
    class PerpetualTimer(threading._Timer):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_Timer'
aspire@aspire:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

[Reportedly a bug](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1163/attributeerror-in-cherrypyprocessplugins) with the upgrade of python from 3.2 to 3.3 where the _Timer module is renamed Timer.

Open "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py3.3.egg/cherrypy/process/plugins.py" in a text editor and replace _Timer with Timer on line 424.

Comment: Indeed. ["This has already been fixed at the commit 01b6adc which is part of the 3.2.4 release."](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1256/threading_timer-does-not-exist-anymore)